# sbt run in docker container suppresses output

Tags: docker, sbt, dockerfile

I am using docker to run sbt tests in a container.
The dockerfile ends with the line (i tried every 3 of them):

```
#CMD ["sbt", "project myproject", "it:test"]
#CMD sbt "project myproject" it:test 2>&1
CMD ["sh", "-c", "sbt \"project myproject\" it:test"]
```

I then build the image with

```
 docker build -f ci-cd/ci-env/Dockerfile -t docker_test:v1 .
```

When I run the container with

```
docker run docker_test:v1
```

I don't see any output after the first 3 lines. Connecting to container's shell tells me that the tests are indeed run but the output is suppressed - I can see only 3 lines instead of the full sbt output:

```
[info] Loading settings for project my-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /my/project
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/my/project/"), "my-build")...
```

I can only get the output when using

```
docker run -it docker_test:v1
```

but -it can't be used in Jenkins.

How do I get the output of sbt test in Docker?

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly you mean output is suppressed ?

Comment: I can see only the first 3 lines of sbt output

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77541385/no-download-progress-shown-when-running-as-part-of-podman-build-or-docker-bui